# How to dynamically set dimensionality for a boost multi_array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I have a function that needs to create a boost multi_array for which the dimensions are not known a priori.  However, the extents ARE known for any given dimensionality.  How do I incrementally build up an extents object for my array?

Something like:

```
array_type::extent_gen<array_type::dimensionality> my_extents;
for (size_type d = 0; d < array_type::dimensionality; d++) {
    extents = extents[5];
}
array_type my_array(extents);
```

Would set an not-yet-determined array to have an extent of 5 in every dimension....

Comment: `extents = extents[5];` ? I dont understand what this is supposed to be

Comment: Trying to get a thing that is like "extents[5][5][5].....[5]" for d 5s

Comment: Consider adding /what/ you want to achieve (not /how/) to the question. Also add the definition of `array_type`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, since the dimensionality of `multi_array` is encoded in the type's template arguments:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
```

Is fundamentally distinct from

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_type;
```

The "best" you might do is have

```
static const int MAX_DIMENSIONS = 10;
typedef boost::multi_array<double, MAX_DIMENSIONS> array_type;
```

And then build the extents to leave the "unused" dimension's extent at `1`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/749afd61e0161606)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static const int MAX_DIMENSIONS = 5;
typedef boost::multi_array<double, MAX_DIMENSIONS> array_type;

array_type make_array(int dims, int default_extent = 5) {
    boost::array<int, MAX_DIMENSIONS> exts = {};
    std::fill_n(exts.begin(), exts.size(), 1);
    std::fill_n(exts.begin(), dims, default_extent);

    return array_type(exts);
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_array(3);
    auto b = make_array(2);

    std::copy(a.shape(), a.shape() + a.dimensionality, std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(std::cout << "\na: ", " "));
    std::copy(b.shape(), b.shape() + b.dimensionality, std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(std::cout << "\nb: ", " "));
}
```

Prints

```
a: 5 5 5 1 1 
b: 5 5 1 1 1
```

Comment: (Note you can subsequently get an array view from that array that transparently hides the unused dimensions, but - again - you'll get distinct static types there)