# Boost multi_array with dynamic rank

Tags: boost

The rank (or `NumDims`) parameter of `boost::multi_array` is a `std::size_t` template parameter.

Is there any way to give the array a dynamic rank instead of static? I'm assuming not, looking at the code but I might have missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a feature of the library. You can emulate it, though:

- [How to dynamically set dimensionality for a boost multi_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648696/how-to-dynamically-set-dimensionality-for-a-boost-multi-array/39657451#39657451)

  Here the dimensionality is not dynamic but arrays of lower dimensions are emulated by fixing the higher dimensions to `1`.
- [Container for boost::multi_array of same type but with different dimentionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670408/container-for-boostmulti-array-of-same-type-but-with-different-dimentionality/26674802#26674802)

  The latter uses variants to store a known set of dimensionalities (with unlimited shapes).